# Symfony admin generator

Tags: symfony1, admin, generator

I have a table A->Users that has a backend generated with symfony admin generator; I have filters and forms too. Is there a way to filter by a get/post request the records that appear when I call backend_dev.php/users, by one of its field (i.e. id field)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Propel or Doctrine? If you want a subset of the users you have to add the following to your generator.yml (inside users folder):

```
config:
  --your config
  list:
    peer_method: YOURFUNCTION
```

I mean the default behavior is to select all, using peer_method you tell symfony to use your custom method. Remember to implement YOURFUNCTION inside  users model.

This works for propel, Doctrine users check this link:

[Doctrine table_method](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_sub_table_method)

Comment: the problem is that I want to pass a variable in get to this function to select the users...

Comment: Then I don't understand your question, can you try to give more info?